# EF Code first - how to add an existing database table?

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have EF Code First to an existing database.
There is an existing table that was not mapped across. How do I do that?
I have followed the [advice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579398(v=vs.113).aspx) and run

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges
```

Followed by

```
update-database
```

Comment: "There is an existing table that was not mapped across. How do I do that?"  Are you saying you want to generate the C# code first entity that would represent the existing table?

Comment: First you'll need to reverse the existing database to code first. This could help: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator

Comment: Yes, I want it to all connect up. I have been trying to do it by looking at the existing code and trying that for my table, but I cannot get it to work. Is there an automatic way of doing it? The brute force way would be to delete and start again.

Comment: Thank you @Karel that effectively solved my problem. All I had to do was delete my existing code and run this and in 5 minutes I had what I wanted. Probably it would be better to use this software to simply include a new table but I hadn't figured out how to do that yet. The software BTW is excellent!